# command-line: Force installation of a downloaded Windows-10 update

Tags: windows-10, command-line, windows-update

```
“wuauclt.exe /updatenow“ % was run as administrator
```

*Windows Update* indicates that 19.03 download status indicates 100%.

What command-line instruction can "move the needle" and initiate the installation of the the newly downloaded v19.03?

Comment: There isn’t one, the command you normally can run, doesn’t apply to feature updates.  Feature updates are automatically prepared and installed in the background.  This has been the case since at least 1703.  Microsoft made significant changes to the feature upgrade experience.  It went from taking multiple hours, to performing the majority of the work, before the first reboot happens.

Answer (score -1):

This is only a comment but I don't have enough rep for it to appear directly under your question.

Have you tried the Windows Update Standalone Installer?

Just type "wusa /h" for a list of commands.

Comment: This suggestion does not apply to feature updates.